# How to get the basic HTTP authentication data with Spring MVC and Java

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

Where can I find **the basic HTTP authentication credentials** (username and password) in the incoming request to my server?

Is it somewhere in the Request object, or is there some other way to get them?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

When a browser sends HTTP Basic authentication info, it basically sends an HTTP Header named `Authorization`

with a value of

`Basic somethinghere`.

The part after `Basic` is really just `Base64.encode("${username}:${password}")`

Check out [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) basic description of the procedure.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16000878/2504224) is a SO answer that describes how you can easily obtain the authentication credentials from the HTTP Header.